# to find total number of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, summation, permutations, relations

I was working out some problem where I needed permutation and combination. I took the cartesian product of $n$ sets where number of elements in each set is even. Further the elements of this cartesian product is divided into subsets as follow:

$G_0 = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)~ |~ each~ x_i~ is~ an ~odd  ~number ~or ~ each~ x_i~ is~ an ~even  ~number\}$ for $1\leq i
\leq n$.
$G_{k_1} = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)~ |~x_{k_1} ~is~even(odd) ~and ~x_i~ is~ an ~odd(even) ~number~ for ~i\neq k_1\}$.
$~~~~~~~~~~~~\textrm{where}\,\,1\leq k_1\leq n$.
$G_{{k_1}{k_2}} = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)~ |~x_{k_1},x_{k_2} ~is~even(odd) ~and ~x_i~ is~ an ~odd(even) ~number~ for ~i\neq k_1,k_2\}$.
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\textrm{where}\,\,1\leq k_1\leq n-1$.
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~\,\,k_1 +1\leq k_2\leq n$.

$\vdots$

$G_{{k_1}{k_2}{\ldots}{k_\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}} = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)~ |~x_{k_1},x_{k_2}\ldots,x_{k_\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} ~is~even(odd) ~and ~x_i~ is~ an ~odd(even) ~number~ \\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~for ~i\neq k_1,k_2\ldots,{k_\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\}$.
$~~~~~~~~~~~~\textrm{where}~~~~~~~~~~~\,\,1\leq k_1\leq n-(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 1)$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\,\, k_1 +1\leq k_2\leq n-(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 2)$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\vdots$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\,\, k_{{\lfloor n/2  \rfloor}-1} +1\leq k_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \leq n$

How to prove that total number of these subsets will be $2^{n-1}$? For small values of $n$ I checked manually but as $n$ increases its a tedious job. Please help or suggest any way to prove this. Thanks for giving your attention.

***The following answer is true for odd numbers. Kindly help in the case of even numbers***

***NOTE:*** n sets with even number of elements means that if $A_1$ is a set with even number of elements, ex 6 elements, then $A_1$ is like $A_1 = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. We know the size of each of the $n$ sets is even. But we don't know anything about the actual size of the sets (or should we assume each set may have a size in $\{2,4,6,\ldots,n-1\}$?). We also don't know the range of the $x_i$ (maybe $1\leq x_i\leq n,1\leq i \leq n$?)

Comment: Sorry sir, for replying late. Each subset in this case has same number of elements.

Comment: Sir, I have edited my question with a note. Is it helpful in any way?

Comment: Just commenting about the notation: (1) to insert text into maths, use the \text tag, so it doesn't get turned into italics; (2) you can just write $1\le k_1<k_2<\ldots<k_m\le n$ and since they are integers it will be understood that $k_1\le n+1-m$ etc, (3) the word "parity" may be useful, so that you could say "all $x_i$ have the same parity" to mean that they are all even _or_ all odd.

Comment: @AndrewWoods Yeah, You are right. In future will consider these things :)

Comment: Dear Monalisa: Very good that you've edited your question to clarify some aspects. It's a good training for you to formulate them more precisely and it helps the reader to support you with fruitful answers. One hint: If you write "each $x_i$ is an odd number or each is an even number." this usually means, that you consider $n$-tupels containing  only odd numbers or only even numbers. Maybe you could discuss with one of your colleagues, how to precisely formulate this question. Nevertheless, it seems you've got an appropriate answer! :-) Best regards,

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Yeah sir, I got the answer and learned many new things too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we set $k=\{k_1,...,k_i\}$ for some $i\leq \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$. Then we have $G_k$ as in you definition. So your question is in how many ways can we choose $k$ such that $G_k$ is a set as in your definition.

This can be calculated by how many different $k$ we can pick, lets call this number $x$. This number equals
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{n \choose i}=x
$$ 
If we now multiple this number by $2$ and realise that ${n \choose i}={n \choose n-i}$. Then we get 
\begin{align*}
2x &= 2\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{n \choose i}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{n \choose i}+\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{n \choose n-i}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i}
\end{align*}

Then with newton's binomial we have that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i}=2^n$. Thus we get that $$2x=2^n\Rightarrow x=2^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Will you please elaborate more in detail. I am unable to catch your point. I tried but not getting anything. sorry

Comment: I have edited my answer, hopefully it is clearer. If not please tell with part you don't understand.

Comment: I got your point. You mean if I take the value of $n$ as 4, then we have $G_0,G_1,G_2,G_3,G_4,~G_{12},G_{13},G_{14}$ subsets and 
 ${n \choose i}$ for n = 4 and i = 0 will give numbers of $G_0$ i.e. only one and                                                                                                                       
${n \choose i}$ for n = 4 and i = 1 will numbers of $G_i$ and that is 4. Am i right?
Thanks for the nice explanation.

Comment: I think you got it.

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't notice it earlier. But the steps you used is only true for odd numbers. How to do it for even numbers?

Comment: Recently when I tried for small numbers, it is not for even numbers. Can you help me with even numbers

Answer (score 1):

Consider a single element of the Cartesian product:
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)$$
Each $x_i$ is an integer, and thus even or odd.
Now consider applying $f(x)=x\operatorname{mod}2$ to each term.
The result will be a binary string of length $n$. For example, $(1,2,3,4,2,7,3)$ would become $(1,0,1,0,0,1,1)$.

Notice that each of your $G$-subsets contains all the elements of the Cartesian product which fit a particular binary profile, or its inverse.
For example, $G_{3,5}$ contains elements fitting the profiles $(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,\ldots,0)$ or $(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,\ldots,1)$, in which the dots represent just zeros and just ones respectively.

Furthermore, the list of $G$-subsets is a disjoint cover of the Cartesian product. By applying the function $f$ to the terms $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$, we get a binary profile which immediately fits exactly one of the subsets.

There are $2^n$ possible binary profiles. Each of the $G$-subsets deals with two such profiles. They are disjoint and cover the Cartesian product. Therefore there must be $2^n\div2=2^{n-1}$ of them.

Comment: Wow. That's really great and nice approach to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful. I don't know which answer deserves the +50 though.